# Read in a file and skip lines that start with a specific string

Tags: matlab, text-files

I'm tryng to read in a text file with Matlab. 
The file is in this format:

string number number
string number number
....

I'd like to skip the lines which start with a specific string. For any other string, I want to save the two numbers in that line.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example with actual data please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take this sample file `file.txt`:

```
badstring 1 2
badstring 3 4
goodstring 5 6
badstring 7 8
goodstring 9 10
```

If a line starts with `badstring` we skip it, otherwise we store the two numbers following the string.

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
nums = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f');
fclose(fid);
ind = find(strcmp(nums{1},'badstring'));
nums = cell2mat(nums(:,2:end));
nums(ind,:) = [];
display(nums)
```

This will read the entire file into a cell array, then convert it to a matrix (without the strings), and then kill any row which originally started with `badstring`. Alternatively, if the file is very large, you can avoid the temporary storage of all the lines with this iterative solution:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
line = fgetl(fid); 
numbers = [];
while line ~= -1 % read file until EOF
    line = textscan(line, '%s %f %f');
    if ~strcmp(line{1}, 'badstring')
        numbers = [numbers; line{2} line{3}];
    end
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid); 
display(numbers)
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it but this is the message error:Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
Message Catalog MATLAB:services was not loaded from the file. Please check file location, format or contents

Comment: Can you please test whether this error also occurs for my sample file? Make sure the formatting is exactly the same and that the file is in the current working directory of matlab or that you provide the full relative path to the file when using `fopen`. It's working flawlessly for me.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault! I fixed it! Thanks!